# How to use shared assets between react and react-native in nxWorkspace

Tags: reactjs, react-native, monorepo, nx-workspace

I have a nxWorkspace with React, React-Native and Nodejs. I've create a shared assets library to use between React and React Native. I'm able to use it with React, but I have no idea how to use it in the React-Native. I've look at the documents and youtbue videos also, but all of them have used with React or Angular.

```js
apps
  - web
  - mobile
  - server
libs
  - shared-assets
```